# ¿Cual es el regex que usa por default el datatable de boostrap?

Tags: c#, sql, regex, datatables

Me gustaría saber cual es el regex que usa la caja de search en el datatable de boostrap, la que esta por default cuando se lo asignamos a nuestra tabla, ya que me gustaría replicarlo en una consulta que me obtendrá esa misma información de la tabla y la exportara en un reporte de Excel, se que el datatable contiene botones que hacen esas acciones, solo que en esta ocasión la impresión de Excel requeriría mas información de la que se visualiza en el datatable y una personalización avanzada.

Así que quiero replicar el regex de search para que puedan imprimir los resultados filtrados del datatable, esa replica la usaría en SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola @dav documentacion indica que tu mismo puedes definir la expresion regular para tu input search.

```
https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()
```

Por lo tanto de acuerdo a tu consulta el regex lo defines tu mismo! [online regex](https://regexr.com/)

Saludos capo.